# What is the equivalent code of `Response.Redirect("~/abc.aspx") in java script?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

What is the equivalent code of `Response.Redirect(~/Account/Login.aspx");` in javascript?

I tried : `window.location="~/Account/Login.aspx"` but the `~` is not accepted in javascript. so, what is the alternative code?

Note: the javascript script is made in the server side in the `Page_Load` method by using `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use

```
window.location='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Account/Login.aspx") %>'
```

EDIT:
if it is created in codebehind, then use

```
string.Format("window.location='{0}';", ResolveUrl("~/Account/Login.aspx"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.location='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Account/Login.aspx") %>';
```

The ~ is replaced by the application URL in .NET, but this is not done in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(_Default), "Redirect", "document.location.href = '" + ResolveUrl("~/Account/Login.aspx") + "';", true);
```

I would ask as to why you are doing a client-side redirect from the server-side though? Would it not be more appropriate to do a `Response.Redirect` instead?